# Live data observer getting called even after observer is remoevd

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have an activity, which instantiates a fragment say B. Fragment B shows a list of users. which i fetch from DB as LiveData. I add an observer to the live data. whenever the onChanged gets called i remove the observer. 
But still whenever the DB changes `onChanged` gets called again and again.

Here is the code for fragment class:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    initRecyclerViews()
    viewModel.liveResult = viewModel.getAllUsers()
    observeData()
}
fun observeData() {
        viewModel.liveResults?.observe(this@UserFragment, Observer(allUserAdapter::submitList))
        viewModel.liveResults?.observe(this@UserFragment, observer)
    }
val observer: Observer<PagedList<User>> = object : Observer<PagedList<User>> {
    override fun onChanged(t: PagedList<User>?) {
        dataChanged()
    }
}

fun dataChanged() {
    // do some work

    viewModel.liveResults?.removeObservers(this@UserFragment)
}
```

Below is the code for adapter class:

```
class AllUsersAdapter(
private val inflater: LayoutInflater) :
    PagedListAdapter<User, MyViewHolder>(diffCallback) {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AllUsersItemViewHolder {
    return MyViewHolder(
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_item, parent, false))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AllUsersItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.setItem(getItem(position))
}

companion object {
    private val diffCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<User>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: User, newItem: User): Boolean {
            val ret = oldItem.phonenumber == newItem.phonenumber
            return ret
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: User, newItem: User): Boolean {
            val ret = oldItem.phonenumber == newItem.phonenumber
            return ret
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is the code for viewmodel:

```
    class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel() {
       lateinit var mUsersList: LiveData<PagedList<MaxwellUser>>

fun getAllUsers() {

    val factory = dao.getUsers()
            liveResults = LivePagedListBuilder(factory,
                    PagedList.Config.Builder()
                            .setPageSize(Constant.PAGE_SIZE)
                            .setEnablePlaceholders(true)
                            .build()).build()
    }
}
```

This is the Dao Query:

```
@Query(Select * from users)
abstract fun getUsers(): DataSource.Factory<Int, User>
```

users table has many fields like name , phonenumber , status , location etc.
i keep on updating the table from background .
I want my fragment to load the data once , and when i remove the observer, it should not get any updates of the db changes.
But the problem is first time , when i load the fragment , the data gets loaded in the list , `dataChanged` gets called. and observers get removed.

But again when Some DB change happens ,my users list keep on updating .

Answer (score 0):

Why do you observe the list two times?

```
viewModel.liveResults?.observe(this@UserFragment, Observer(allUserAdapter::submitList))
viewModel.liveResults?.observe(this@UserFragment, observer)
```

You can submit your list to adapter in `dataChanged` method.

Comment: i observe the live data second time , to get the onCHanged callback , to set the title of my screen based on the count of the items in the live data list. And also to remove the observer. as you can see the code pasted above

Comment: i tried adding the submitList in dataChanged , But did not work out.